# Condition return value in C99

Tags: c, optimization, standards, c99

I am trying to optimize some code and I was wondering if the return value of a condition like

```
(1>0)
```

is always 1 in c99 ? I couldn't find the answer on the web and the few tests I made with gcc seems to indicate this is true. But is this part of the langage specification ?

The exact code (marching squares algorithm) :

```
to_run->data[(y / 2) * (my_grid->width / 2) + (x / 2)] =
    (up[0] > level) +
    (up[1] > level) << 1 +
    (down[0] > level) << 2 +
    (down[1] > level) << 3;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

> #### C99 §6.5.8 Relational operators
>
> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=` (greater than or equal to) shall yield `1` if the specified relation is true and `0` if it is false. The result has type `int`

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The draft C99 spec says:

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and
>   `>=` (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it
>   is false. The result has type int.